# Error 1066, Not unique table/alias how to Fix it?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a query like this :

```
$this->db->select('acctstarttime, SUM(acctinputoctets) as total');
    $this->db->from('radacct');
    $this->db->group_by('MONTH(acctstarttime),YEAR(acctstarttime)');
    return $this->db->get()->row()->total;<br/>
```

**EDIT**
the JOIN come from another query, and that query is :

```
$query = $this->db->get('radcheck',$sampai,$dari);
    $this->db->join('radacct', 'radcheck.username = radacct.username',$sampai,$dari);
   return $query->result_array();
```

as you guys can see, i'm not even using "JOIN" statement,but the output of that query is :

> Not unique table/alias: 'radacct'
>
> SELECT `acctstarttime`, SUM(acctinputoctets) as total FROM `radacct`
>   JOIN `radacct` ON `radcheck`.`username` = `radacct`.`username` GROUP
>   BY MONTH(acctstarttime), YEAR(acctstarttime)

what happen ? why is it suddenly do a JOIN ? please help me, thanks in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: It joins because you use the `$this->db->join()` method. What did you expect?

Comment: If you're using CodeIgniter like I suspect, double check the documentation here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Comment: yeah, sorry, how do i fix it btw ?

Comment: I think you're looking for `where()` instead of `join()`

Comment: silly me, i should've put the "Get" after JOIN, not before -_-